# Proper handling of foursquare venues unicode characters in iOS app

Tags: ios, unicode, collation, foursquare, emoji

What's the proper way to handle unicode characters in an iOS app that calls the foursquare API?

Our current setup calls the foursquare API from our iOS app, and returns XML (yes, we're changing this to JSON).

While testing our app, we discovered the hard way that this foursquare [location](https://foursquare.com/v/hotel-sentosa/4d69be3c82cba0936bf5ded8) borked our app -- apparently because we did not setup to handle the two Emoji characters in the venue name.

What's the proper way to handle unicode characters at each level?

In Objective-C, as we call the foursquare API?
In our our WCF web services, as we return XML data to the app?
In SQL Server 2008, as we store a place name that may contain unicode characters?

On the database side, I know that we need to make some changes to the Collation settings, among other things.

What changes, if any, are needed to support unicode 6.1 correctly in our iOS app and web services?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out an example of a foursquare venue with emoji in it's name; that's what I was looking for when I Googled this page.  

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to convert a unicode string to another encoding then back to unicode. If the converter doesn't know what the unicode character is then it could do something strange(e.g. the converter might convert one of the new sad pussycat emoji characters to a square root sign).

This might happen without you explicitly doing it depending on how you have your database setup, the XML encoding you use, your HTTP server configuration, etc.

Unicode 6.1 just adds characters, the encoding is exactly the same(i.e. some codes that didn't map to anything now map to things).

Comment: Looked up the unicode chars in the venue example ( https://foursquare.com/v/hotel-sentosa/4d69be3c82cba0936bf5ded8 ) and they are in the private-use block, so these [pretty much] never map between character encoding.